# Does anyone know of settings that would block javascript from running in chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

1. Does anyone know of any settings that would block javascript in chrome?
2. If so how do I remove them?
3. I check all the settings and none would let me read or check the console log in the developer tools.

Comment: You want to debug if the javascript is running or failing? By default, all browsers will run your javascript. There are 2 reasons as to why your script may not run. 1. The script has not been downloaded 2. The script has errors

Answer (score 2):

You likely need to enable Javascript under `chrome://settings/content/javascript`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is good .  I'm checked out .  But it might be my code from class.   It's a 2015  class.  when i type console.log(typeof ....) it doesn't return even though i have it open in Dreamweaver.

It also doesn't allow me to pass functions  either  in the console . Even if i input everything in the console.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using developer tools as well, follow these steps:

1) click on three dots at right top of chrome >> more tools >> developer tools

2) now press ctrl + shift + P or Command+Option+C (on Mac)

3) start typing javascript, you will find an option to disable javascript